# Finding last <td> of each <tr> using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I had two tables with same class name "Test", I need to find out last  of each  of first table using JQuery

Please help me out.

Comment: I need to find the last td of each tr using jquery. my table class name is tablesorter

Comment: Hello banalaramu. [so] is not the type of site that simply writes code for you. You'll have to show us that you have at least *tried* to accomplish this before posting here... Where exactly are you having problems?

Comment: Have you tried the aptly named [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) or [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/)?

Comment: who -1'd the poor fella

Comment: (not my DV) @luk - Who ever it was probably feels that there was not enough research effort done by the OP before posting here...

Comment: they are new... where is the love people. someone doesnt like me either for getting my code slightly wrong, haha

Answer (score 23):

jQuery 1.1.4 introduced the [last-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/):

> Description: Selects all elements that are the last child of their parent.
>
> While :last matches only a single element, :last-child can match more than one: one for each parent.

```
$("table:first tr td:last-child");
```

Comment: There's no JQ 1.14: https://code.jquery.com/jquery/

Answer (score 14):

```
$('table:first tr').each(function() {
  var lasttd=  $(this).find(':last-child')
  //your code
});
```

Comment: can i know the reason ..

Comment: `#table` won't find the first table and `$("td:last")` won't find the last td in your row but the last td in your dom

Comment: actually by mistake i have given '#'

Comment: @sasi: I miss read your code when I upvoted, but your code is slightly off, probably didnt deserve a downvote: http://jsfiddle.net/z2Wvc/ here is a rough example, your `td:last` is not using the `.each` index you have built.

Comment: @Luke i had updated the code..

Comment: @sasi: I've not changed my vote. you code works. I gave up after -2 ;)

Comment: @LukeDuddridge thanks Luke, in the hurry i've done some mistakes,this wont be done again..

Answer (score 9):

Loop through each tr and get the last td with `:last`

```
$('table:first tr').each(function(){
$(this).find('td:last').addClass('LastTD');
});
```

Comment: $("table tr:last-child td:last-child").each(function(){
   $(this).addClass('LastTD');
})